# Implication of convergence in rth mean

Tags: self-study, convergence

I'm trying to show that if $X_n \rightarrow X $ in $r$-th mean, then $E|X_n|^r \rightarrow E|X|^r$. (Edit: should have said with $r \ge 1$)

My question is whether the following steps are sufficient or not:

$[E|X_n - X|^r]^{\frac{1}{r}} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Setting $r=1$

$E|X_n - X| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

And so:

$E|X_n| \rightarrow E|X|$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Hence

$E|X_n|^r \rightarrow E|X|^r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Lemma 6.7 of [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ysv3Jycux04C&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=convergence+rth+mean&source=bl&ots=xanK9MKmLy&sig=gx52Ss4CbTX2q2i8a6JxLgDBqac&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lyIqUYncLIOw0QWxt4DYCg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=convergence%20rth%20mean&f=false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument linked by T. S. Eliot goes as follows. With $X_n \xrightarrow{r} X$, and for the $r \ge 1$ case.

In the Minkowski inequality use $U = X_n - X$ and $V = X$, then:

$[E|U + V|^r]^{1/r} \le [E|U|^r]^{1/r} + [E|V|^r]^{1/r} $

$[E|X_n|^r]^{1/r} \le [E|X_n - X|^r]^{1/r} + [E|X|^r]^{1/r} $

So that:

$ [E|X_n|^r]^{1/r} - [E|X|^r]^{1/r} \le [E|X_n - X|^r]^{1/r}$

Similarly, interchanging $X$ and $X_n$

$ [E|X|^r]^{1/r} - [E|X_n|^r]^{1/r} \le [E|X - X_n|^r]^{1/r}$

Meaning:

$| [E|X_n|^r]^{1/r} - [E|X|^r]^{1/r}| \le [E|X_n - X|^r]^{1/r}$

And we know the RHS goes to zero.